# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm asking another of the essential meta questions as a precursor to some *great* news, Expats is going to be advancing to the public beta stage at some point this week!<sup>1</sup> You all have done a fantastic job of building what appears to be a really strong site in the making.

We're going to need leadership from within this community to help guide the site on its journey to a graduated site. I'm looking for three people that would like to step up take on this position, in accordance with [our theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). Great candidates have the following qualities:

- Consistently patient and fair when dealing with other users
- Have a little time each week to devote to moderating the site
- Willing to help jump start promotional activities, and guide new users as they find the site for the first time

You'll also have our ear, as a liaison, between this community and the Stack Exchange community team.

Are you interested? Nominate below with whatever text you'd like to offer about yourself and why you want the job, and include a link to your profile on the main site. Do you feel strongly that someone else would be a great moderator? Feel free to nominate them as well, explaining why you feel strongly about them as a potential candidate, and link to their main profile as well.

Third-party nominations need to be accepted by the person you nominate, they can either leave a comment to accept, or edit your post with whatever detail they wish to add.

I'm starting this a bit early due to the activity we saw during the private beta, I have a feeling we're going to see quite a few new faces once we open - the sooner I start the process of looking, the sooner I can get a great team in place.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Should be this week, don't panic if it's next.</sub>

---

***March 20, 2014*** - Update

Because we got such a huge amount of attention on opening day (which isn't going to be subsiding in the near future), I'm very likely going to begin appointments as early as *today*. If you're reading this and interested in joining the team, I need to see your nomination *very* soon.

You might begin to see diamonds next to names that have nominated here, that's simply me getting people in a position where they can be of the most use while I continue making selections and contacting folks. I'll be writing a formal 'welcome, moderators' meta post after I have all three in place.

Comment: *Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites*

Comment: @Dirty-flow Doh, forgot to convert to wiki, that basically fixes it.

Comment: I have no problem with either Mark or Dirty-flow and upvoted both nominations but isn't it a problem that we are on track to get two moderators from travel.SE, nominated by travel.SE contributors? (I am also active on travel.SE under another name)

Comment: @GaëlLaurans Actually, neither of us are mods on Travel..

Comment: But you were in the past and are pillars of the community there, which is my point.

Comment: Yes, I was, but @Dirty-flow has never been. Just clarifying :)

Comment: Glad I posted this early, first day out we ended up with 6 questions on the hot list, front page of HN and now we're climbing our way through Reddit.

Comment: Could you be a moderator for the site? ;-)

Comment: @Manishearth I plan to be a 'fourth mod' here, at least initially. You'll also probably see some of our expat employees participating here quite a bit, and pitching in to clean up when the hot questions party bus rolls through, which I suspect is going to be a frequent thing.

Answer (score 13):

I nominate [Mark Mayo](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/97/mark-mayo). Mark made a wonderful initial moderator for Travel.SE, is a "serial expat" so has a huge range of knowledge on the topic, as his experiences both here and on Travel.SE shows!

(I believe Mark would be reluctant to stay on after the initial time, but as with Travel we can hopefully talk him into starting out as one)

Comment: OK, after thinking about it since the beta started, and more intently since you nominated me, firstly, thanks for the nomination, and yes, I'll accept if the community will have me.  I'm going to be around the site for a while anyway, that's for sure, and I like helping out where I can.

Answer (score 12):

I nominate [Dirty-flow](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/73/dirty-flow).  We need someone with European knowledge for the Schengen / EU / EEU questions, laws and timezones.

Comment: Plus nobody could argue with a mod with that avatar!

Comment: LOL! I'm a little bit surprised. I accept the nomination. I hope that I can use my experience on Travel.SE to make this site a great place for high quality questions.

Comment: @MarkMayo Except me. *evilgrin*

Comment: Yes, we need someone who'd be strong agaist US-perspective closing as too localized when "it's only moving between 2 EU provinces" or "it affects only Luxemburg, it's like a small city in US" ;)

Answer (score 6):

Since it already started I'm also nominating myself, as a semi-experienced expat originally from Hungary, but also living in both Germany and now in the UK. I'm also very curious about other countries, not only ones in Europe, but others as well.

Though I'm not a very high rep user elsewhere on the SE sites, I did my fair share on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120917/sztupy?tab=activity&sort=reviews) of StackOverflow, and I'm involved on the [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133343/sztupy) site, especially on topics about the issues in the current close/review system. You can also check my [expat.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/25/sztupy) profile and my [global SE profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/41583/sztupy).

Comment: I was just coming to this page to nominate you. +1 from me!

Comment: This candidate's fashion sense _alone_ qualifies them, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 5):

I will throw [myself](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/127/strongbad) into the moderator ring in response to wanting someone who is not actively part of Travel.SE. I am pretty active on TeX.SE and use it as a resource to ask questions and learn and answering when I can. I am also active on Academia.SE where I try and help people find the information they need. I am a US expat who has been living in the UK for 5+ years.

I have never been a diamond moderator on an SE site, but I have access to the review told on Academia.SE and try and work my way through the review queues and participate in meta and chat.

Comment: Have you been a moderator on any of those sites? Experience with the moderation tools as a high-rep user?

Comment: @Gagravarr see edits. Never a diamond mod, but have used the high rep review tools.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to put my name forward. I have never been a moderator on any StackExchange sites, but would enjoy spending some time on it.

Usually, I tend to hang out on StackOverflow and Ask Different, as I am inclined towards the techy. But the ins and outs of expat life are of course always at the forefront of the mind for anyone who lives 'in another country'.

I am a UK citizen who has lived in Thailand for the last ten years, along with all the bureaucracy, political upheaval, headaches and coups d'etat that that entails.

It was only this morning that I came across this site, but I feel that it can make an excellent resource for people suffering the frustrations of expat life, as well as helping people who are faced with the possibility of living in a country in which they are not a citizen, to make decisions that can have far-reaching consequences in their life.