# Please give a warm welcome to your new moderation team!

Tags: discussion, moderation

The response to [my call for moderators](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/who-should-the-moderators-be) was overwhelmingly good. Everyone seems to share a common goal and vision for the site, and I think I'm not alone in wishing that this resource existed *years* ago as more and more pioneering folks pulled up their roots and planted them in new countries.

This was tough, because *every single person* that nominated would have done a fantastic job, but initially, we're going to go with a team of three. Without further adieu, please welcome your new moderation team:

[image: profile for Mark Mayo at Expatriates Stack Exchange, Q&A for people living abroad on a long-term basis]


[image: profile for SztupY at Expatriates Stack Exchange, Q&A for people living abroad on a long-term basis]


[image: profile for StrongBad at Expatriates Stack Exchange, Q&A for people living abroad on a long-term basis]

Did I overlook anyone? Almost certainly - the number of users demonstrating the right blend of experience, patience and topic knowledge was extremely high - almost *everyone* actively participating would probably make a good moderator. That's why we hold democratic moderator elections shortly after a site graduates.

Until then, I'm confident that we'll be in good hands with the folks above. Please give them a warm welcome, and remember - this is a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Nice to get the site one more step towards graduation.

Comment: Gotta keep you on your toes though - when's the newsletter subscription link appearing? ;)

Comment: THERE'S AN UN-HANDLED COMMENT FLAG IN THE QUEUE ZOMG MAYO YOU SLACKER!!!!! (I have no idea when that turns on, so I'm using clever misdirection to avoid embarrassment) (I'll find out, in other words).

Comment: is there? I just accepted the terms, after ploughing through the edits, so it should be showing for me now?

Comment: Congrats folks!

Comment: "I think I'm not alone in wishing that this resource existed years ago" -- I proposed it 2 years ago! :-)

Comment: Congrats to @MarkMayo, who I know from travel, and you other strangers I don't know from a bar of soap too (-;

Comment: Congrats everyone! I also think this site has a lot of promise, and wish it had existed a decade ago, when I first started living in a country I had never been to before :)

Comment: I don't know if that welcome should be warm and dry, or warm and humid, so please take my warm welcome and set the humidity level to your personal preferences :)