# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Expatriates's [first moderator election](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: ouflak]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking your pro-tem moderator, Mark Mayo, who will be stepping down as moderators as well as [the previous pro-tems](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/162/6331) who helped this site through its beta phase.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6308636709093376/0).

---

Due to some confusion when setting up this election, the Community Team ended up doing so for a single slot, when we had intended to do so for two slots. As such, we contacted the runner up to join the team too — let's welcome him into the team as well:

[image: Scott Earle]

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, and welcome onboard!

Comment: It's a privilege. Looking forward to helping out where I can. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I know I was included after this answer was written, but ... thanks anyway :)